# displaying a returned array in a popup box

Tags: php

Hi I am currently using a PostCode Anywhere API subscription to fetch addresses based on a post code, step 1, is to get a range of addresses based on the post code, then step 2, is to save that ID and full address details in a separate table.  At the moment I have this working using the following code:

```
global $strTableName;
$postcode= $params["value1"]; 
//Set Post Code Variables
$Key = $_SESSION["PAFKey"];
$SearchTerm = $postcode;



//Build URL Request
$url = "http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/PostcodeAnywhere/Interactive/Find/v1.10/xmla.ws?";
$url .= "&Key=" . urlencode($Key);
$url .= "&SearchTerm=" . urlencode($SearchTerm);

//Make the request to Postcode Anywhere and parse the XML returned
$file = simplexml_load_file($url);

//Check for an error, if there is one then throw an exception
if ($file->Columns->Column->attributes()->Name == "Error") 
{
throw new Exception("[ID] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Error . " [DESCRIPTION] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Description . " [CAUSE] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Cause . " [RESOLUTION] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Resolution);
}

//Copy the data
if ( !empty($file->Rows) )
{
foreach ($file->Rows->Row as $item)
{
$Data[] = array('Id'=>$item->attributes()->Id,'StreetAddress'=>$item->attributes()->StreetAddress,'Place'=>$item->attributes()->Place);

$newStreetAddress = str_replace("'", "", $item["StreetAddress"]);
$newPlace = str_replace("'", "", $item["Place"]);


$sql = "insert into Global_temp_address (id, StreetAddress, Place, PostCode, AddedBy) values ('".$item["Id"]."', '$newStreetAddress', '$newPlace','$SearchTerm', '".$_SESSION["user"]."')";  CustomQuery($sql);

}}
```

This does work, but I have only been able to do so by creating a temporary table, then using a two part form (2nd part is then used to select address on dropdown, after selecting this, the temp table is then wiped).

This isnt the best process, I would like to know how to get the returned data and display this in a popup dropdown box or something similar?  Any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: The question is not clear. I don't know postcodeanywhere. What is the purpose of the second part? De we need to know about part I to solve part II. You seem to have done some part of this part 2 assignment but are stuck. Tell us.

Comment: You're giving yourself hard work using XML. Postcode Anywhere also provides JSON which is so much easier!

Comment: thankyou Farkie could you possible tell me more

Comment: in response to PaulH's question, there are two parts to using postcode anywhere, the first part (query) returns an array of possible address based on the search term which is the post code (which is a free lookup), you use this arrray to then select the actual address, which links to part 2, the array returns a unique ID back to postcode anywhere which gets all the records for that one specific address, i.e. address line, 1, 2, 3, town, county, country, etc, this part you pay for, that data is copied into a reference table